# Ошибка кодировки в виндовс 10: файлы в visual студио сохраняются в неверной кодировке

Tags: python, visual-studio, кодировка, windows-10

Сначала была проблема в том что русский язык в visual studio не отображался для этого я воспользовался этим способом:
*Пуск (ПКМ) -- параметры -- время и язык -- формат даты, времени и региона -- язык -- административные языковые параметры -- изменить язык системы -- поставить галку на Бета версии использовании юникода UTF-8*

Все было прекрасно пока не дошел до того что мне нужно сохранять таблицы на русском языке, и у нас снова ошибка кодировки. Сохранение файла через visual studio с кодировкой Utf-8 with BOM спасает ситуацию, однако это костыль. Подскажите как устранить эту проблему кодировки [image: текст без костыля][image: Через visual studio содержимое текста прекрасно передается]

```
with open(f"data\{n}_{count}.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writher = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
        writher.writerow((
            product, callories, proteins, fats, carbonohydrates
        ))
```

Comment: Все сохраняется в нормальной кодировке - в utf-8, как и указано у вас в коде при открытии файла. Это Excel, простите, тупой, он такую кодировку в csv не понимает. Чтобы в нем нормально отображалось, записывайте csv в кодировке cp1251.

Comment: О вы правы! Спасибо) поставил кодировку Windows-1251 и все заработало